# Setting a multicell range to variant works, but setting a multicell range to string does not work. Why?

Tags: vba, excel

The code below works. I want to read all strings from a table. The code below automatically changes my variable vSheets into an array that has room for all of the strings in the table.

But if I change Dim `vSheets As Variant` to `Dim vSheets As String`, I get an error message on the line `Dim vSheets As Variant`.

```
Sub GetSheets()
    'Get sheet names from tToggleSheets.DatabodyRange
    Dim wksTables As Worksheet
    Dim loSheets As ListObject
    Dim vSheets As Variant

    Set wksTables = GetSheetByCodename(ThisWorkbook, "wTables")
    Set loSheets = wksTables.ListObjects("tToggleSheets")
    vSheets = loSheets.DataBodyRange
End Sub
```

Why does VBA automatically expand the variant variable to make room for all the strings in `loSheets.DataBodyRange`, but does not expand the string variable in the same situation?

Which variable type should I use in the situation above, variant or string?

Answer (score 0):

[DataBodyRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.databodyrange.aspx) return Range type of data. I'm beginner in vba, but I think Variant is a good choice for this case.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I think it returns the default value of range which is range.value, at least that is what is saved into the variant variable. The variant doesn't store the range objects in this case.

Comment: Maybe should you try Range data type and next try convert to string?